# non-existent /index.html url is visited by someone on my wordpress website. What could be the reason? What can I do to prevent it?

Tags: wordpress

Someone is consistently visiting my wordpress website with non existent url /index.html
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1h0s.jpg)

Can anyone tell me what is he doing? What can i do to prevent him?
also he comes to the site almost 80 times a day with session duration of 5 minutes

Edit1:
Also I have added htaccess rule to redirect that url to some other website.
but my analytics still shows that url visitor.

I am attaching a fresh image of my analytics. It shows 5 visitors on that url [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnkBg.jpg)

Edit:2
If I add the htaccess rule to block all urls having index.html. I get the following error:
"You donot have permission to access /wp-content/cache/all/index.html on this server"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just some scan bot that is trying to understand what your website structure looks like. It shouldn't harm you, but if you want to kill that habit of your "visitors" you could simply add  something like (not tested) to your .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch index\.html>
        Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Edit:

With the following .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch index\.html>
        Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

If i visit mysite.com/index.html -> i get a forbidden
If i visit mysite.com and browse it like a normal WP site -> All good

What are you missing? Isn't this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: but its ip is not logged in the iplogger. also he comes to the site almost 80 times a day.
What normal bot comes 80 times a day.
i can't use the  code provided by you as my homepage becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Does that give u 500 error? try to use <files instead of <FilesMatch and use index.html w/o slash. 
So it would be 
<files index.html>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Comment: Still result is same. It says you are not allowed to access this url. But i think he's trying to create a new fake page because the non existent page has a tile showing in the analytics

Comment: As soon as i have a break i will test on my WP test ENV

Comment: Sure. kindly try that

Comment: can i have a chat with you.
here they are not allowing me
it would be very helpful

Comment: I am getting this error
You donot have permission to access /wp-content/cache/all/index.html on this server

Comment: That was some kinda important piece of information to have, you should update your question with this piece of information and get a new response, i guess i can't help you any further